# What should i call a "Paragraph with a header"...?

Tags: single-word-requests

What should i call the set of "brief paragraph with a header".

In a single word, ex - Segment OR Paragraph OR Section OR anything else..?

Comment: Single word requests should have an example sentence - a sentence that conveys some context.

Comment: I almost always call them sections.

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph itself is still just a paragraph in its own right.

However, the so-called header that introduces the text it's part of is, in general terms, a [*heading*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heading):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> 1 a : something that forms or serves as a head especially : an inscription, headline, or title standing at the top or beginning (as of a letter or chapter)

What the *heading* does is delineate a [**section**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/section):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2** : a distinct part or portion of something written (such as a chapter, law, or newspaper)

It might be ambiguous, but in that definition "such as" is referring back to "something written," not to "a distinct part or portion." So, for instance, the chapter would have *sections*, not be called a *section*.

---

In short, in this context, a *section* is composed of a *heading* (sometimes called a *section heading*), followed by text, which is normally composed of one or more paragraphs (although sometimes, for example, just bullet points or figures).

These paragraphs are just part of the section.